# Are Azure cloud service names global?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

When one creates a cloud service, Azure says its FQDN is [name-given].cloudapp.net.

Does that mean cloud service names are global and therefore I must append my company name to avoid stepping on someone else's toes?

Does that mean I'm vulnerable to name stealing? Like, mycomapny.cloudapp.net?

What happens if my company name is "Ap Pleinc" and someone else is "Apple Inc" and they both want to use appleinc.cloudapp.net?

Comment: An FQDN is global by definition. As for the various "what happens", the domain is `cloudapp.net`, not `apple.com` or `appleinc.com`. Whatever holds with any other hoster holds here as well. First one wins but no-one uses the default names anyway, every company registers and uses its own FQDNs

Comment: How do I tell Azure to use mycompany.com as domain instead of cloudapp.net?

Comment: This is described in [Configure a custom domain name for an Azure Cloud  Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/)